# Apple Push Notification Service

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an alarm app in iphone. To set alarm I have to use APNS (Apple Push Notification Service). Can you suggest me how to do this or some important tutorial regarding this.

Comment: You can also check and follow these guys. It seems they are working on different stuff onto APNS integration. [http://www.monopush.com](http://www.monopush.com)

Comment: If you want to integrate Push Notifications without using Local Notifications, you can use http://pushwizard.com too. It is free for unlimited devices. There are a few other providers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here for authoritative information from the [Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html). You might also search [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=push+%5Biphone%5D), and [on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=apple+push+notification+tutorial). If you can explain in more detail what, exactly, you're looking for help with, we can help with more specific information.

If your plan is to have someone configure alarms on some web site (or desktop app, or whatever), and the use push to send a notification to the device when the alarm "goes off", I encourage you to reconsider that. Push is an unreliable medium (in the same sense as UDP): no guarantees are made as to when, or whether, the notifications will be delivered. It is *not* something you should depend on to happen at a particular time. It does *not* get you around the prohibition on background processes on iPhone.

That said, you can certainly try. The Programming Guide I linked above will get you started. There are definitely many APNS tutorials on the web. And if you have *specific* questions, this site can certainly help. But right now, you're asking, essentially, "how do I write my app?" That's a pretty broad scope for a Q&A site like this.

Comment: I am developing an alarm app. So, when user sets alarm, how to trigger an event at alarm set time. If you have such kind of exp then please help me. I would be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you actually mean Local Notifications, not Apple Push Notification Service (APNS). Using Local Notifications you can set timers that will show an alert to the user after a specific time. Using APNS you can basically push events from a server to the users handset.

I suggest you read the [Push Notification Service Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).